# Can't get information about SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am creating some ERS (Error Reporting Service) in my SQL Server 2008 R2. Introducing part of the report should contain some basic information about version of SQL Server, Windows info etc...

I have two queries which work fine on my virtual machine, but at my host machine I have problem with `sys.dm_os_windows_info`.

This basic query throws the error:

```
SELECT * 
FROM sys.dm_os_windows_info;
```

Error:

> Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid object name 'sys.dm_os_windows_info'.

Comment: What version is the host machine running? It doesn't matter what version you have. What is the result of select @@VERSION on the host machine?

Comment: I was looking at @@version. My result is: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM) - 10.50.1600.1 (X64)   Apr  2 2010 15:48:46   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) (Hypervisor)  @Sean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need at least SP1 on SQL Server 2008 R2 (10.50.2500 or later) to use this.

[`sys.dm_os_windows_info` Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh204565(v=sql.105).aspx).

[SQL Server Versions](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/783.sql-server-versions.aspx)

Comment: Where is that mentioned in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh204565.aspx)

Comment: Didn't help. Am I missing something? @Joe

Comment: @JackDawson you've got an unsupported version (service pack).